# phpMyAdmin error with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For the first couple days of using XAMPP for Mac, I was successful in beginning to learn MySQL via phpMyAdmin. Then, it randomly stopped letting me log in, displaying the following error:

phpMyAdmin - Error

Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.

I've checked other forums, and they have not helped at all. I'm new to all of this, so I don't know much about anything regarding this, I've only used the program for about a day. PLEASE HELP!
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What error is in the web server logs?

Comment: Sorry in advance for being inexperienced but how do I pull up the web server logs?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if mysql is running. If it is, post your Serverlog, without it we cannot help you in any way.

Comment: Ok, it seems like the problem is I need to create a password, and I'm struggling like crazy to access the sql command line. Every single forum I look up is telling me commands that don't work so can somebody please just tell me how do I access the sql commands on mac/XAMPP or how do I change my root password? THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Comment: generally XAMP should not be used for Internet access, if you only need a password for testing an application. Just make a new user, and let the root user be without passwort.